# WooCommerce, if Billing country is BE and Shipping country is NL, change VAT to 9%

Tags: php, function, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

The title is allready telling what I try to achieve. For a client of ours we run a B2B webshop and they asked the following and I don't know how to do this.

If a customer has a billing address in Belgium and also is shipping the product to (in) Belgium they don't have to pay VAT. If the customer has a billing address in Belgium and wants to ship to the Netherlands, they do have to pay 9% VAT.

I think this can be done with a function/ hook but to be honest I don't know where to start.

Can somebody point me in the right direction. I would be very thankfull.

Kind regards!